# Using CSS inline on one list

Tags: css

I am trying to apply my CSS file to 2 of my lists

```
<ul class="list1">
    <li>Cat</li>
    <li>kittens</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list2">
    <li>Pizza</li>
    <li>Popcorn</li>
</ul>
```

I want only one of them to be inline so I'm trying

```
ul.list1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

but the inline won't work unless I do

```
li {
 display: inline;
}
```

which applies to all my lists. How do I make it son only inline affects one list?

Comment: What you want is `ul.list1 > * { display: inline;}`.

Comment: What's the downvote for on this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you want one of the lists to be *horizontal*, like so:

```
.list1 li { display: inline; }
```

Look up how to use [descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors), it is one of the basic powers of CSS.

Comment: Thank you! I just started learning CSS/Html a few days ago. I was wondering is there a style faux pas on brackets? Like what you did versus mine?

Comment: @user3145912, no. I put the brackets on one line when there the rule is short. Usually I break mine up. If you like the answer, accept it when you can :)

Comment: The CubanMissile is faster than I.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the specificity of your selector.  For example...

```
ul.list1 li { display: inline; }
```

For further complexity as an example...  If you have both of these lists appearing twice in your site, once inside a div with the ID #content, and once inside a footer widget with ID #widget.  Then you can target the list inside #content by typing.

```
#content ul.list1 li { display: inline; }
```

Here is a link to an article to the W3C Wiki on [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

The above link will give you everything you need to know concerning combinators, pseudo-selectors and pseduo-elements.  Learn this and you can conquer the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 .list1 li {display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will make all of your listings inline, as I can understand, this is not your intention.

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Instead, you should specify that you only want one of the lists elements to have this style. You should therefor use the following code.

```
.list1 li {
    display: inline;
}
```

This will make all list entries within the `list1` class inline.